# Extract Information from BeautifulSoup bs4.element.Tag using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing to extract some information via web scraping from website https://www.kerastase.com.au/  .
As an example, I'm focusing on Best Seller items (7 items).
I have been able to extract name, description and price using the following code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.kerastase.com.au/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

prod_names = soup.find_all("h3", class_="c-product-tile__name")
prod_names = [prod.get_text() for prod in prod_names]
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="c-product-price__value")
prices = [float(price.get_text()[2:]) for price in prices if (len(price) > 0)]
prod_descs = soup.find_all("p", class_="c-product-tile__description")
prod_descs = [desc.get_text() for desc in prod_descs]
```

However, extracting rating and number of reviews seem to be more complicated. It is a nested div.
I have been able to extract caption of the first item using the following command; however it is a mess, and don't know what to do after this step:

```
soup.findAll('figcaption', class_="c-product-tile__caption")[0]
```

Here is an example of full caption of one item I get:

```
<figcaption class="c-product-tile__caption"> <div class="c-product-tile__caption-inner"> <div class="c-product-tile__wishlist"> <button aria-label="Add to Wishlist Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil" aria-pressed="" class="c-add-to-wishlist" data-analytics='{"products":[{"pid":"3474637116088","title":"Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil","description":"","url":"https://www.kerastase.com.au/collections/elixir-ultime/elixir-ultime-pride-edition-hair-oil/3474637116088.html","imgUrl":"https://www.kerastase.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-kerastase-master-catalog/default/dw377882d1/2022/Elixir%20Ultime/Pride/1.%20Product.jpg","currency":"AUD","price":65,"name":"Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil","subname":"Iconic nourishing hair oil for all hair types. Kérastase will be donating to Minus18, subsidising LGBTQIA+ Inclusion Workshops for schools across Australia.","id":"elixir-pride","salePrice":65,"brand":"Kérastase","category":"others/collections/elixir ultime","productTopCategory":"products","variant":"100 ml","size":"100 ml","color":"","fragrance":"","stock":"in stock","autoReplenishmentInterval":"not present","upc":"3474637116088","regularPrice":null,"isProductSet":false,"isProductGroup":false,"isBundle":false,"bundleID":"","rating":5,"numberReviews":2,"vtoState":"not present","collection":["Elixir Ultime"],"customizations":{"engraving":"not present"},"badges":"none","remainingStock":null}],"label":"elixir ultime pride edition hair oil::3474637116088","category":"{{dataLayer.page.category}}"}' data-component="product/AddToWishlist" data-component-options='{"pid":"3474637116088","url":{"add":"https://www.kerastase.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-kerastase-au-ng-Site/en_AU/Wishlist-AddToWishList","remove":"https://www.kerastase.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-kerastase-au-ng-Site/en_AU/Wishlist-RemoveFromWishList"},"text":{"title":{"add":"Add to Wishlist","remove":"Remove from Wishlist"},"accessibility":{"addAriaLabel":"Add to Wishlist Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil","removeAriaLabel":"Remove from Wishlist Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil"}},"isLabel":false}' title="Add to Wishlist"> <span class="h-show-for-sr" data-js-wishlist-text="">Wishlist</span> </button> </div> <h3 class="c-product-tile__name"><a data-js-product-name="" data-lora-datalayer='{"products":{"3474637116088":{"name":"Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil"}}}' href="/collections/elixir-ultime/elixir-ultime-pride-edition-hair-oil/elixir-pride.html"> Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil </a></h3><p class="c-product-tile__description"> Iconic nourishing hair oil for all hair types. Kérastase will be donating to Minus18, subsidising LGBTQIA+ Inclusion Workshops for schools across Australia. </p> <div class="c-product-tile__info m-multiple-items"> <div class="c-product-tile__info-item c-product-tile__rating"> <div data-bv-productid="elixir-pride" data-bv-redirect-url="/collections/elixir-ultime/elixir-ultime-pride-edition-hair-oil/elixir-pride.html" data-bv-seo="false" data-bv-show="inline_rating" data-component="product/BazaarvoiceService"> </div> </div> <div class="c-product-tile__info-item c-product-tile__price"> <div class="c-product-price" data-component="product/ProductPrice" data-component-options='{"pid":"3474637116088","reloadData":{"configid":null},"dataModelId":"productprice"}'> <span class="c-product-price__label h-hidden" data-js-pricelabel="">Old price</span> <span class="c-product-price__value m-old h-hidden" data-js-standardprice=""></span> <span class="c-product-price__label h-hidden" data-js-pricelabel="">New price</span> <span class="c-product-price__value" data-js-saleprice="">A$65.00</span> </div> </div> </div> <div class="c-product-tile__variations-group"> <div class="c-product-tile__swatch-group"> </div> <div class="c-product-tile__variations"> <div class="c-product-tile__variations-label">One size available</div> <div class="c-product-tile__variations-single-text"> <span data-js-pid="">100 ml</span> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="c-product-tile__actions m-add-bag-enabled" data-js-producttile-actions=""> <div data-component="global/ComponentPlaceholder" data-component-options='{"_lazyload":true,"reloadData":{"id":"productmainaction","section":"product","configid":"producttile","reloadUrl":"https://www.kerastase.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-kerastase-au-ng-Site/en_AU/CDSLazyload-product_productmainaction?configid=producttile&amp;data=3474637116088&amp;id=productmainaction&amp;pageId=homepage&amp;section=product"}}'> <button class="c-button m-expand-for-medium-down c-product-add-bag__button m-loading"> <span>Loading ...</span> </button> </div> </div> </figcaption>
```

How can I get products rating and number of reviews from this?
Example: "rating":5,"numberReviews":2

(It is probably possible to get all product info from the above, but don't know what the best method is).

Comment: 1) What is the error you're having? 2) What research have you done? As in, how is this not a question that people will try to answer but will be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find main specific tag for product details data is inside in `button`    tag and it contains `json` formatted data so we can use data and find the relaticve information

```
main_tag=soup.find_all("div",class_="c-product-tile__figure")
import json
dict1={}
for i in range(len(main_tag)):
    json_data=main_tag[i].find("button")['data-analytics']    
    details=json.loads(json_data)
    price=details['products'][0]['price']
    rating=details['products'][0]['rating']
    numberReviews=details['products'][0]['numberReviews']
    title=details['products'][0]['title']
    dict1[i]={'name':title,'price':price,'rating':rating,'reviews':numberReviews}
```

Output:

```
{0: {'name': 'Elixir Ultime Pride Edition Hair Oil',
  'price': 65,
  'rating': 5,
  'reviews': 2},
 1: {'name': 'Nutritive 8HR Magic Night Hair Serum',
  'price': 67,
  'rating': 4.5701,
  'reviews': 749},
  ....
  }
```